# Using beautiful soup to obtain class contents with a conditional

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I would like to use beautiful soup to find tags where the child tags(gains or losses) are greater than 0. I would then like to print the contents of the inner tags "gains" "losses" and "band.textualrepresentation". This is essentially the script I want (although this one doesn't work).

```
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def parseLog(file):
        file = sys.argv[1]
        handler = open(file).read()
        soup = Soup(handler)
        for anytype in soup('anytype', 'gains'.string>0 || 'losses'.string>0):
                gain = anytype.gains.string
                loss = anytype.losses.string
                band = anytype.band.textualrepresentation.string
                print gain loss band

parseLog(sys.argv[1])
```

I am running into troubles early on, I can't even print the contents of gains, let alone print the contents that meet a certain criteria. My current Script

```
def parseLog(file):
        file = sys.argv[1]
        handler = open(file).read()
        soup = Soup(handler)
        for anytype in soup.findall('anytype'):
                gain = anytype.fetch('gains')
                print gain

parseLog(sys.argv[1])
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./soup.py", line 13, in <module>
    parseLog(sys.argv[1])
  File "./soup.py", line 9, in parseLog
    for anytype in soup.findall('anytype'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

.

**Sample Input**

```
      <anytype xsi:type="GainLossStruct">
         <band>
          <textualrepresentation>
           22q11.1
          </textualrepresentation>
         </band>
         <gains>
          2
         </gains>
         <losses>
          1
         </losses>
         <structs>
          0
         </structs>
        </anytype>
        <anytype xsi:type="GainLossStruct">
         <band>
          <textualrepresentation>
           22q11.2
          </textualrepresentation>
         </band>
         <gains>
          0
         </gains>
         <losses>
          1
         </losses>
         <structs>
          0
         </structs>
        </anytype>
        <anytype xsi:type="GainLossStruct">
         <band>
          <textualrepresentation>
           22q12
          </textualrepresentation>
         </band>
         <gains>
          0
         </gains>
         <losses>
          0
         </losses>
         <structs>
          0
         </structs>
        </anytype>
```

**Sample output**

```
2  1  22q11.1
0  1  22q11.2
```

.

.

**Update**
The current solution

```
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def parseLog(file):
        file = sys.argv[1]
        handler = open(file).read()
        soup = Soup(handler)
        for anytype in soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (hasattr(x, 'gains') and int(x.gains.string) > 0 or hasattr(x, 'losses') and int(x.losses.string) > 0)):
                gain = anytype.gains.string
                loss = anytype.losses.string
                band = anytype.band.textualrepresentation.string
                print gain, loss, band

parseLog(sys.argv[1])
```

Still returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./soup.py", line 15, in <module>
    parseLog(sys.argv[1])
  File "./soup.py", line 9, in parseLog
    for anytype in soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (hasattr(x, 'gains') and int(x.gains.string) > 0 or hasattr(x, 'losses') and int(x.losses.string) > 0)):
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 659, in __call__
    return apply(self.findAll, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 849, in findAll
    return self._findAll(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 377, in _findAll
    found = strainer.search(i)
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 966, in search
    found = self.searchTag(markup)
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 924, in searchTag
    or (markup and self._matches(markup, self.name)) \
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 983, in _matches
    result = matchAgainst(markup)
  File "./soup.py", line 9, in <lambda>
    for anytype in soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (hasattr(x, 'gains') and int(x.gains.string) > 0 or hasattr(x, 'losses') and int(x.losses.string) > 0)):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Even when I reduce the for loop to

```
for anytype in soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (hasattr(x, 'gains'))):
        gain = anytype.gains.string
        print gain
```

I still get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./soup.py", line 13, in <module>
    parseLog(sys.argv[1])
  File "./soup.py", line 10, in parseLog
    gain = anytype.gains.string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be:

```
for anytype in soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (int(x.gains.string) > 0 or int(x.losses.string) > 0)):
    gain = anytype.gains.string
    loss = anytype.losses.string
    band = anytype.band.textualrepresentation.string
    print gain loss band
```

python `||` is `or` and we need to convert string to number before perform integer comparison, e.g. `int(x.gains.string)`. Hope this help.

Comment: actually you could leave as a string and do `x.gains.string > '0'`

Comment: make sense, but only in the case that data is in well-form. Or it will be very hard to find bug if string is `'' > '0'` or `'foo' > '0'`. we need error instead of silently produce incorrect result.

Comment: I still get   `File "./soup.py", line 13
    print gain loss band
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` as an erro with this code

Comment: should be `print gain, loss, band`

Comment: @digitake if you want to validate the data, this should probably be a separate step, also it's not true that `'' > 0`, the empty string is less than everything ;)

Comment: Thank-you, I'm still getting the same `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'` after a lot of lines saying `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./soup.py", line 15, in <module>
    parseLog(sys.argv[1])
  File "./soup.py", line 9, in parseLog
    for anytype in soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (int(x.gains.string) > 0 or int(x.losses.string) > 0)):
  File "/Users/jacob/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 659, in __call__
    return apply(self.findAll, args, kwargs)
  ...`

Comment: which means some of your element doesn't contain `gains` or `losses` child. you can further guarding it by

soup(lambda x: x.name=='anytype' and (hasattr(x, 'gains') and int(x.gains.string) > 0 or hasattr(x, 'losses') and int(x.losses.string) > 0))

Comment: @mamymoo it's different thing to perform an explicit code validation which causes more time and line of code. it's just a coding style that help you catch a subtle bug. since we assumed that data will come in this format. and it doesn't matter if it's empty string or not. whole point is it produce "unintended behaviours" in the code.

Comment: @digitake Thank-you, I made the change to my code but I am still receiving the same error, I've posted an update in my question where I outline the error more

Comment: @Jacob ok at this point `x` has `gains` but it is None object. so you might need more guarding `(hasattr(x, 'gains') and x.gains is not None)`

Answer (score 2):

I would parse the entire document into a pandas dataframe, then do whatever manipulations after; this might make the data-cleanup process more transparent and easy to understand.

I'm going to use `xmltojson` here since I'm not familiar with beautiful soup (although I had to enclose the whole thing in "document" tags since to make it valid XML):

```
import xmltojson
import pandas as pd

with open(file) as f:
    j = eval(xmltojson.parse("<document> "+ f.read() + "</document>"))

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(j['document']['anytype'])
df.columns = ['type', 'band', 'gain', 'loss', 'struct']
df[(df.gain > '0') | (df.loss > '0')][['band', 'gain', 'loss']]

      band gain loss
0  22q11.1    2    1
1  22q11.2    0    1
```

Comment: I receive this error when using this code
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open(file) as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found`